# Azure eventhub sending several float array messages in python

Tags: message-queue, azure-eventhub

I have three float arrays of data (A,B,C) that I want to send it to event hub.

The issue here is that the classes are nested and I can't figure out how to shape the data to be able to send successfully.

Here is the code that I am trying

```
logger = logging.getLogger("azure")


ADDRESS = ""
USER = ""
KEY = ""


try:
    if not ADDRESS:
        raise ValueError("No EventHubs URL supplied.")

    # Create Event Hubs client
    client = EventHubClient(ADDRESS, debug=False, username=USER, password=KEY)
    sender = client.add_sender(partition="0")
    client.run()

    x_value = np.arange(100)
    try:
        start_time = time.time()
        for i in range(100000):
            A = np.asarray([1,2,3,4])
            B = np.asarray([2,3,4,5])
            C = np.asarray([3,4,5,6])
            message = [A, B, C]
            sender.send(EventData(body = message))
            time.sleep(1)
    except:
        raise
    finally:
        end_time = time.time()
        client.stop()
        run_time = end_time - start_time
        logger.info("Runtime: {} seconds".format(run_time))

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

In this way, I am seeing the error 'ValueBody' object has no attribute 'append'
I think by types, the class encodes the message differently. 
Instead of sending a single message with a serial string, I want to send the message in a parallel way, and receive them something like this:

1. Receive one eventdata with the form of the list [A,B,C]
2. Receive three eventdata A, B, C separately, like calling three different objects basis.

For the second way, I am not sure if it would work since I am using only one partition and that may have the three eventdata A, B, C mixed when I receive them and I do not want that.

Comment: Hi Brian, do you have any more issues about your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed with ms support, the feedback is that: **it only works for a list of string or bytes, but does not work for a list of int.**

And also you should note that, even it sends a list of string, when receive the list, it will concatenate the all elements of the list to compose a single message. For example, if there is a list ["a","b","c","d"] for sending, when receive it, it will show this "abcd" as a whole string.

I have tested it by myself, the above information is correct.

So for your case, you should consider change the list to a string or json string. when receiving it, you can format the data to what you need.

Hope it helps.